# Site works fine in all browsers, except IE7 and lower, site has no style at all

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

The website I'm working on is currently working fully on latest chrome which is what I'm using, but when I use tools like [IE NetRender](http://netrenderer.com/index.php) to check its compatibility with older IE versions, the site comes up plain, with no styling **AT ALL**!
However, IE8 is on a completely different level. The site is looking almost as good as it's on chrome/firefox/whatever.

I tried using IE9.js, modernizr, IE Hacks, everything - but nothing worked.
Somehow it all seems to take effect only on IE8+.
It's as if IE7- don't even load the stylesheet.

I also checked my code for errors in the CSS/HTML markup but all of the errors point at the IE css hacks.

What could possibly be the cause to this? I'm literally frustrated with it.
The site (just a development page) is http://kanjiman.0zed.com/

Any help will be MUCH appreciated.
Please try to render the page using [IE NetRender](http://netrenderer.com/index.php) and see what I'm talking about.

P.S; I did try to Google/search for a solution - but in none the situation was as bad as mine.

EDIT:
The problem was IE9.js - I found this out thanks to Fabio's answer.
Whether you want to keep it or not is up to your project requirements and your priorities.
I personally am going to keep it since as both Rob / Felis commented, IE versions 6/7 are DYING! I'd rather provide a better user experience for now rather than supporting and spending more time with older browsers.
Also, this is only a matter of about 3 lines, so if your site starts to gain more IE7 traffic (I doubt it will even worth it), it's always changeable.
**Thanks Rob, Felis and Fabio :)!**

Comment: Your page does recognize the styles (initially), but as soon as the page finished loading, the styles disappear: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yJM3j.png. My recommendation? Stop caring about IE6 and 7, and spend your time more wisely.

Comment: You've code after closing tag `</html>`. Don't even bother to debug your page into IE6/IE7 while it's invalid. edit: Why did I talk about IE6/IE7? Don't even bother to debug your page in any browser while it's invalid ;)

Comment: @RobW Really? I didn't know that... that's the disadvantage of using a screenshot... I did give up on IE6, it's dying. As for IE7, I think there's still hope. I will eventually give up though if I don't get an answer. The time I spend trying to solve these stupid IE problem is ridiculously unproductive. By the way, I just visited your page, I saw you posted a guide to making a VM for testing which is actually not a bad idea at all. Thanks! P.S I also subscribed to your sendtask extension - looks good! :)

Comment: @FelipeAls - I'm well aware of it... That's the code that the free host I'm testing on is injecting... I'm going to change soon though. It didn't have any impact on any browser though, could this possibly be the problem?

Comment: You should install VMs from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575 They're a reliable solution (I mean for testing, not speaking about the browser included ;) ). As for supporting more or less IE6 and IE7, it depends of your requirements or those of your clients. If the future of its business is in China, well you're doomed (and what takes more time to be done shouldn't be done for the same price, obviously)

Comment: @xTCx I can understand that IE8 users exist (because upgrading an operating system is not an option to the average user; talking about Windows XP which cannot run IE9+), but IE6/7 is close to dead, don't bother supporting these unless you've got too much time or a specific request.

Comment: Injected code> it's unlikely that a GA script could do that.

Comment: @FelipeAls thanks for the professional, business approach. However, this is a blog I'm working on for myself... that's why it's harder for me to deal with these rather little imperfections. The target audience is too vast and general. However, I believe I should really stop worrying about those since no one answered me yet so I'm guessing that it's either something bigger than I expected or just not that important. As for the code, the **host** injected it in order to track traffic/bandwidth. It's just a temporary one though - as I said, I'm going to get another one.

Comment: @RobW Thanks. This is not a request and I can't really be bothered with it anymore to be honest. I will just give on this as I see I'm not getting any answers anyways. Thank you for making me realize it... and all the hours I spent scratching my head... hehe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i see in Internet Explorer 7

```
<style _7="
article,aside,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{display:block}mark{background:#FF0;color:#000}">CSS Stylesheet</style>
```

this is what should be there:

```
<style>
article,aside,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{display:block}mark{background:#FF0;color:#000}</style>
```

For some reason, you are assigning the style as an attribute for the style tag making it useless for internet explorer. Why dont you use css files for styling instead of mixing it with the html source code?

Hope it helps

Comment: Uh? I've never seen it in my code :O Could you please specify the line in the source code you're seeing it in?

Comment: Nevermind - found the problem. Please edit your answer so other people with the same problem notice - The problem was IE9.js and I found about it thanks to your note! :) link: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/